# Chaning default class name in Maven archetype:generate

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

Is there a way to set up default class name in Maven?

I'm creating the new project with this command:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=path.to.project \
  -DartifactId=ProjectName
```

I get this structure of files:

```
ProjectName
    |---src
    |     |--main
    |     |    |----java
    |     |           |----path
    |     |                 |-----to
    |     |                        |----project
    |     |                               |-------App.java
    |     | 
    |     |--test
    |         |----java
    |                |----path
    |                      |-----to
    |                             |----project
    |                                    |-------AppTest.java
    |---pom.xml
```

I want to create app with different default name. Let's say, to replace `App.java` with `NewAppName.java` and `AppTest.java` with `NewAppNameTest.java`.

Is there a way to modify my command to get desired outcome?

Comment: I don't know a way how to do that (I never stumbled upon that question). But the real question should be: Why do you want to do that? What is the underlying problem you are trying to  solve? This really looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I want to create projects in Maven (started using it on for class, so it will be a lot of small projects) without renaming created classes manually after creation. I mean, I can do everything manually, but Maven is automation tool and I really hope it is enough flexible for not leaving this task to me.

Comment: Looking for the exact same problem, help me if you find anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

But you can write your own Archetypes, naming the default class file name: *NewAppName.java* in your project.

reference:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html